# Alternative php://input to multipart/form-data

Tags: php

According PHP Manual `php://input` is not available with `multipart/form-data`. Theres an alternative to this? (http://www.php.net/manual/wrappers.php)

Code:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $put_vars);
```

It's not working because my Restful receives `multipart/form-data` that contains `$_FILES['image']`.

Comment: Why do you need raw input if you have the data posted as multipart/form-data? If that is the case, you should be able to just use the superglobals.

Comment: One thing that's not mentioned in the question I linked to is that in PHP 5.4 you can use [enable_post_data_reading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading).

Comment: @MikeBrant do you mean `$_POST` and `$_FILES` superglobals? They are null

Comment: @Artefacto Its not duplicated as my server uses `NGINX` instead `Apache`. Theres any fix to `NGINX`?

Comment: @Artefacto My server uses PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch

Comment: @LucianoNascimento It's still a duplicate; the question does not mention Apache. If you want to know how to rewrite request headers in nginx that's a separate question (and I have no idea what the answer is).

Comment: And $_REQUEST also is null?